# Regex to take first set after Space and want to remove $ with same regex

Tags: c#, regex

My input string:-

**" $440,765.12  12-108(e)\n3 "**

Output String i want as:-

**"440,765.12"**

I have tried with below regex and it's working but I am not able to remove $ with the same regex so anyone knows how to do the same task with below regex?

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^(.*? .*?) ");
var match = rx.Match(" $440,765.12  12-108(e)\n3 ");
var text = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

**output after using above regex:-
 $440,765.12**

I know I can do the same task using string.replace function but I want to do the same with regex only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
var result = Regex.Match(s, @"\$(\d[\d,.]*)")?.Groups[1].Value;
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%24%28%5Cd%5B%5Cd%2C.%5D*%29&i=%20%24440%2C765.12%2012-108%28e%29%0D%0A3%20):

[image]

**Details**

- `\$` - matches a `$` char
- `(\d[\d,.]*)`  - captures into Group 1 (`$1`) a digit and then any 0 or more digits, `,` or `.` chars.

If you want a more "precise" pattern (just in case the match may appear within some irrelevant dots or commas), you may use

```
\$(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%24%28%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%28%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%7B3%7D%29*%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%3F%29&i=%20%24440%2C765.12%2012-108%28e%29%0D%0A3%20). Here, `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?` matches 1, 2 or 3 digits followed with 0 or more repetitions of `,` and 3 digits, followed with an optional sequence of a `.` char and 1 or more digits.

Also, if there can be any currency symol other than `$` replace `\$` with [`\p{Sc}` Unicode category](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/list.htm) that matches any currency symbol:

```
\p{Sc}(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)
```

See yet [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cp%7BSc%7D%28%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%28%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%7B3%7D%29*%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%3F%29&i=%20%24440%2C765.12%2012-108%28e%29%0D%0A3%20).

Comment: @KARAN  Glad it is. Just in case the context of the match is messier than in your example, I added two more expressions.